# React Dataviz: How to calculate AND display simple, but lots of data?

Tags: reactjs, analytics, victory-charts, nivo-react

I'm currently undergoing a re-work of a basic analytics system I built. Let me explain the paradigm and data simply. In the database we have records for user analytics, tracking their **attendance/viewership** (1 list for datetimes (ISO) of when they enter, 1 for when they leave).

The main problem is displaying a single, comprehensive, interactive, and responsive chart of this dynamic data. The data is fetched on a fixed-time interval (once every 15s or so). Our application is an SPA (single page application) and this analytics graph will render client-side.

So, the flow of information currently is

- 1. Fetch user attendance data from API (done, easy)
- 2. Construct analytics data based on user attendance data

  - mapping user attendance from arrays to JSON keyed by DATE and COUNT ie.

```
[
    {x: new Date(a), y: attendanceCount[a]},
    {x: new Date(b), y: attendanceCount[b]},
    {x: new Date(c), y: attendanceCount[c]}
    {x: new Date(d), y: attendanceCount[d]},
]
```

- 3. Render analytics data

  - through a graphing library, that renders in some responsive, interactive and visually pleasing format.

The first is based on intervals, but is quite inefficient. Essentially, based on the desired graphing interval (datetime range), I evenly divide that interval into smaller intervals. For each of those intervals, I iterate through each user's entrance and leave event arrays. Obviously, at worst case it's near O(n^3), and for large amounts of information it fails hard at being optimized. What this approach does well is displaying the viewership at any instantaneous timeframe because I judge whether each user is attending, and has not left within each interval calculation.

The next idea is instead of iterating through all user's attendance, I collate all data into a single list, keyed by event time and type (ie {type: 'enter', event: '2022-10-25T15:47:09.639Z'}), and then iterate ONCE through this large array, adding or subtracting from a viewership total. This means that to calculate the attendance for any specific interval, I need to calculate viewership from the very first event, since new events add or subtract to previous viewership counts.

[image]

Through some testing, it seems that event-based calculations are much more efficient. I'm very much open to new suggestions for analyzing viewership, but my main issue is that of rendering this data, as calculating these arrays for event-based points takes less than 1 second on large amounts of data (many more than would be typical!).

[image]

Currently, I'm attempting to utilize Nivo (Line/ScatterPlot) (seen above) to display this data, as it looks and feels very polished. However, when attempting to render this many points on either a Line or ScatterPlot graph, it takes upwards of 5 seconds to render. Logically, this makes a lot of sense, as when Profiling the rendering process, each individual point is rendered, thus adding up to a lot of scheduling.

[image]
While researching, I came across [Victory](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/) (seen above) and tried it. It has the wonderful addition of zooming + panning (great additions!), but lacks in the polish that Nivo has. However, it is very wonderful at rendering, because we can use a render filter to render a maximum amount of points, while maintaining a good range display of data. This makes rendering much, much faster than Nivo, since we can get good clarity for the data while balancing how many/which points are rendered!

Essentially, here's what I'm asking:

CONSTRUCTING ANALYTICAL DATA:

- Is there a better way to calculate viewership given each user has a list for their entrances and their exits?
- Is it better to process this data server-side then stored, so then all that's needed is refreshing of this processed analytical data, and rendering it

RENDERING ANALYTICAL DATA:

- Should I use Victory for it's in-built functionality and figure out how to style it better?
- Should I try and come up with a homebrew filtering method when constructing my graph data, to group together points, to optimize the number of points I'm rendering?
- Should I just skip the middleman and learn D3 for building a custom analytics component?

Any and all help is appreciated. This is one of those problems that I've hastily built a solution for without much research or constitution for scalability for the future. Not only is the current solution inefficient, but lacks accuracy and finesse, and I would like some good insight as to how to approach this.

Thank you very, very much.

Comment: The only useful advice I have: don't render more points than the number of pixels in the chart's width. A popular approach is to have a function (getter) outputting only the currently visible data. This works well with libs having built in transitions between different sets of data (apexcharts, chart.js). Although well researched, your question is asking for opinionated advice. We could only speculate about what's more important to you or which task (mapping data or tweaking a lib's UI) is going to be easier (or more effective) for you (or your team).

Comment: @tao good point, I see exactly what you mean. I think overall my goal is to hopefully get someone that has been in the same position to give advice by close experience. Although you have a really good point, and gave me the inspiration to apply a filter similar to what I've applied to the Victory chart (filters the data points to remove an even amount from throughout the dataset, based on the length of the set), and it now renders MUCH MUCH MUCH quicker.

Comment: I'm more experienced than most with charts. To the point one might think I even like them. To be fair, I do like maths/trigo and animations. I've done countless chart implementations and also made bespoke charts when what the client wanted wasn't possible using an existing lib. What I haven't done is work for a charts lib company, but i had minor contributions to a few. Despite all that, I don't feel more qualified than you to answer the question. You know the requirement, the client and the resources best. You are in the best position to make a decision. I'm sure it will be a decent one.